# Why is MathJax.startup.promise undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mathjax

I'm trying to get MathJaX v3 running on node, and this is the code I have:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const glob = require('glob');

const { AllPackages } = require('mathjax-full/js/input/tex/AllPackages.js');

glob('**/*.html', { "ignore": ['node_modules/**/*.html'] }, (_, res) =>
    res.forEach(r => {
        const htmlfile = fs.readFileSync(r, 'utf8');

        MathJax = {
            loader: {
                paths: { mathjax: 'mathjax-full/js', custom: '.' },
                require: require,
                load: ['[custom]/xypic.min.js'],
            },
            tex: {
                packages: AllPackages.concat('xypic'),
                inlineMath: [['$', '$']]
            },
            startup: {
                input: 'tex',
                output: 'chtml',
                adaptor: 'liteAdaptor',
                document: htmlfile,
            }
        }

        require('mathjax-full/js/components/startup.js');

        MathJax.startup.promise.then(() => {
            const adaptor = MathJax.startup.adaptor;
            const html = MathJax.startup.html;

            //  Remove the stylesheet
            adaptor.remove(html.outputJax.chtmlStyles);

            //  Output the resulting HTML
            fs.writeFileSync(r, adaptor.doctype(html.document) + adaptor.outerHTML(adaptor.root(html.document)));
        });
    }));
```

I get the error:

```
mathjax.js:34
        MathJax.startup.promise.then(() => {
                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

I'm using https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-demos-node and MathJax-src for reference, but I still can't seem to figure it out.

EDIT: I still haven't figured out how to get a custom extension to work on node.js, but this is the latest progress:

```
import { readFileSync, writeFileSync } from 'fs';
import glob from 'glob';

import { mathjax } from 'mathjax-full/js/mathjax.js';
import { TeX } from 'mathjax-full/js/input/tex.js';
import { CHTML } from 'mathjax-full/js/output/chtml.js';
import { liteAdaptor } from 'mathjax-full/js/adaptors/liteAdaptor.js';
import { RegisterHTMLHandler } from 'mathjax-full/js/handlers/html.js';
import { AllPackages } from 'mathjax-full/js/input/tex/AllPackages.js';
import { Loader } from 'mathjax-full/js/components/loader.js';
import 'mathjax-full/js/util/entities/all';

MathJax = {
    config: {
        loader: {
            paths: { custom: '.' },
            require: require,
            load: { '[+]': ['[custom]/xypic.min.js'] },
            failed: err => console.log(err)
        }
    },
    loader: Loader
};

MathJax.loader.ready('xypic').then(() => {
    glob('**/*.html', { "ignore": ['node_modules/**/*.html'] }, (_, res) =>
        res.forEach(r => {
            const htmlfile = readFileSync(r, 'utf8');

            // Register the HTML handler
            const adaptor = liteAdaptor();
            RegisterHTMLHandler(adaptor);

            // Create a MathJax document
            const tex = new TeX({ packages: AllPackages.concat('xypic'), inlineMath: [['$', '$']] });
            const chtml = new CHTML();
            const html = mathjax.document(htmlfile, { InputJax: tex, OutputJax: chtml });

            // Typeset the document
            html.render();

            //  Remove the stylesheet
            adaptor.remove(html.outputJax.chtmlStyles);

            //  Output the resulting HTML
            writeFileSync(r, adaptor.doctype(html.document) + adaptor.outerHTML(adaptor.root(html.document)));
        }));
}, err => console.log(err));
```

Strangely, it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `MathJax.startup.promise` can only be used within `MathJax.startup.ready()`. 
See [the documentation here](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/configuration.html#performing-actions-after-typesetting).

Try:

```js
MathJax.startup = {
    ready() {
        MathJax.startup.defaultReady();
        MathJax.startup.promise.then(() => {
            const adaptor = MathJax.startup.adaptor;
            const html = MathJax.startup.html;

            //  Remove the stylesheet
            adaptor.remove(html.outputJax.chtmlStyles);

            //  Output the resulting HTML
            fs.writeFileSync(r, adaptor.doctype(html.document) + adaptor.outerHTML(adaptor.root(html.document)));
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Well, the code does nothing, as the end result.